# some examples of algorithm complexity of nested loops?

Tags: algorithm

I have seen that in some cases the complexity of nested loops is O(n^2), but I was wondering in which cases we can have the following complexities of nested loops:

- O(n)
- O(log n)    I have seen somewhere a case like this, but I do not recall the exact example.

I mean is there any kind of formulae or trick to calculate the complexity of nested loops? Sometimes when I apply summation formulas I do not get the right answer.

Some examples would be great, thanks.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, but a single loop over a collection will take `O(n)`, where `n` is the size of the collection, and two nested loops over the same collection will take `O(n^2)`.  Not sure what you have in mind for `O(log n)`, but traversing down a full binary tree with `n` nodes would take `O(log n)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example for you where the time complexity is O(n), but you have a double loop:

```
int cnt = 0;
for (int i = N; i > 0; i /= 2) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        cnt += 1;
    }
}
```

You can prove the complexity in the following way:

The first iteration, the j loop runs N times. The second iteration, the j loop runs N / 2 times. i-th iteration, the j loop runs `N / 2^i` times.
So in total: `N * ( 1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + … ) < 2 * N = O(N)`

---

It would be tempting to say that something like this runs in `O(log(n))`:

```
int cnt = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < N; i *= 2) {
    for (int j = 1; j < i; j*= 2) {
        cnt += 1;
    }
}
```

But I believe that this runs in `O(log^2(N))` which is [polylogarithmic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithmic_function)